# Bar button item on every view with specific controller function

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have to display a navigation bar button item on almost every view in the project.

I extended `UIViewController`

```
extension UIViewController{
    func addNavBarItem(){
        //add the bar button item
    }
}
```

And I call `addNavBarItem()` on the `viewDidLoad`. However, the action taken when this button is tapped can be different for each view. Is there a way to set the target for this button to the actual view controller that called this method? Ideally I would want something like....

```
extension UIViewController{
    func addNavBarItem(){
        //do stuff
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OriginalViewController.doSomething), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }
}
```

But `OriginalViewController` isn't available. Is there a quick solution or alternative pattern I should employ?

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Yes I am using a `UINavigationController`. I will try this.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that I use is to subclass `UINavigationController` and put my navigation bar item code in to the `willShowViewController` delegate method like so...

```
class MyNavigationController : UINavigationController {

    override func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        super.navigationController(navigationController, willShowViewController: viewController, animated: animated)
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_menu"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: viewController, action: "doSomething")
        viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    }

}
```

This means when you add the target you can reference the exact `viewController` that is being shown by the navigation controller.